# How do I configure a property of a static class in Spring.NET?

Tags: .net, spring.net

How do I configure a static class via Spring .NET?

Consider the following class:

```
static class Abc
{
   public Interface xyz
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public void Show()
   {
      xyz.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the static class? Can't you create a "normal" (non-static) class and instantiate with singleton scope?

Comment: its utility class like tracing so it is static.

Comment: This code won't compile, since property `xyz` and void `Show` are instance members, which cannot be declared in a static class. They should be declared static as well.

Comment: Consider reading the following questions on the use of static classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c/729805#729805 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576853/what-is-the-use-of-a-static-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a workaround can help..
This is not a static class but it works like one

```
namespace Nyan {
    public class Util{
        protected Util(){} //to avoid accidental instatiation

        public static string DATETIMEFORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";

        public static DateTime parseDate(string sDate)
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, DATETIMEFORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}

<object id="Util" type="Nyan.Util, Nyan" singleton="true">
     <property name="DATETIMEFORMAT" value="HH-mm-ss" />
</object
```

and is used like any other static class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime sDate = Nyan.Util.parseDate("15-15-15"); //parsed with injected format
}
```

Comment: Yes it may solve my problem partially.however here parseDate() is a static so it will work.but in my case Show() is not a static function. so how shal i make a call to it.

Comment: yeah sorry for the mistake.i need to define xyz property and Show() method as static.