# Dependency injection into a static class

Tags: c#-4.0, spring.net, static-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure Property of a static class via spring .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773132/configure-property-of-a-static-class-via-spring-net)

I want to inject the value for a property inside the static class using spring .net.
Code snippet:

```
Public static Abc
{
Public static IInterface IInterface{get;set;}
}
```

here i want to inject the IInterface value inside the Abc staic class though spring .net config.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if you can do it.

Static classes don't really work well with dependency injection.

You will be better off creating the class as a normal class and setting it up as a singleton within the container. I'm pretty sure spring.net will allow this..